# order by nulls first in descending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table called `books` which has a integer column `ordering`, and `created_at` column which is date time.

I would like to get the null rows of ordering to come on the top with the descending order in which they are created, after that i would like to get the non null ordering rows in ascending order.

Here's the query I have tried

```
select * from books order by ordering asc nulls first;
```

I am getting null ordering rows on the top, but those are in ascending order. Is there a way I can get descending order of null rows based on created_at desc and then use the ordering column to sort the remaining rows in ascending order

The relevent Rails query is

```
Book.order('ordering ASC NULLS FIRST')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, I think you're looking for:

`Book.order('ordering ASC NULLS FIRST, created_at DESC')`

This will sort by `ordering`, and then by `created_at` in results that have the same `ordering`.

Comment: Thanks. Doubt: so the records which already have ordering won't be touched in the second order by?

Comment: exactly, the second order by is superseded by the first and can't "break" it.